# requirements.txt packages do not update in a virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, pip, virtualenv

Need to install packages from **requirements.txt** to an *virtualenv* on amazon linux

**requirement.txt** contains:

```
pandas == 0.17.1
pymongo == 3.2.1
```

Already in the virtualenv, typed that command:

```
(venv_exporter)[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx core-exporter]$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Got that at the end of the command:

```
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas, pymongo
  Running setup.py install for pandas ... done
  Running setup.py install for pymongo ... done
Successfully installed numpy pandas pymongo
```

Running that command give me that:

```
(venv_exporter)[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx core-exporter]$ pip freeze
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.4
six==1.10.0
```

Why I don't see my installed packages in the list?

And obviously my code is saying the packages (from the requirements.txt) are missing

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue with Python virtualenv on Amazon Linux.

Create a new virtual environment, update pip and then try to install your *requirements.txt* file.

```
$ pip -U pip
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```